# python warnings saying "Name "X" can be undefined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, undefined

I am pretty new to programming and I have made an app which works fine but I get warnings saying "Name "X" can be undefined". What does this mean and how could I get rid of the warning? I am using Python 3.8 with Intelij IDE 2020.1.

Here is a screenshot of my issue:

[image]

Here is a minimum repo of my code:

```
print("1. school a \n2. school b")
while True:
    try:
        school_number = int(input("\nEnter the number of what school you are at: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That was an invalid number.  Please try again...\n")

current_day = input("Please enter what day it is (mon/tue etc): ".lower())

if school_number == 1:
    school_name = "school A"
    cost = (7.50 * 2)
    leave_time_multiplier = 1.15
    if current_day == "mon":
        start_time = 09.30
        finish_time = 14.30
    else:
        pass

if school_number == 2:
    school_name = "school B"
    cost = (9.50 * 2)
    leave_time_multiplier = 1.25
    if current_day == "mon":
        start_time = 17.00
        finish_time = 20.30
    else:
        pass

# renames the days
if current_day == "mon":
    day = "Monday"
else:
    day = "Other"

leave_time = start_time - leave_time_multiplier - 1

print("\nOn {} at {}: It will cost {:.2f} return. You start at {:.2f} and finish at {:.2f} You should leave at"
      "{:.2f}".format(day, school_name, cost, start_time, finish_time, leave_time))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`finish_time` will be undefined in case of: `school_number` not equal to 1 or 2, `current_day` is not equal to "mon", etc. In such cases, your script will raise an exception. So you have to define `finish_time` somewhere above line with `if school_number == 1:`

Comment: Awesome thanks alot ! `cost, leave_time_multiplier, start_time, finish_time, school_name, day = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` above the if statements sorted this

Answer (score 1):

You must add a third condition where the value does not equal 1 and 2 numbers. Because if the user was input another number than 1 or 2, all variables that you print will not be created.